# How do I replace the text I searched and that is now highlighted?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to replace the `"` by `'` in all the text that are found with regular expression `(\w)"(\w)`. For instance :  `s"t` should become  `s't`.

I run the regular expression with the *Mark* tab, so now all the text that matched `(\w)"(\w)` are marked.

Now I would like to use the *Replace* tab to replace all the `"` by `'` but only in the marked text.

● I tried to run do this in the *Replace* tab : replace  `(\w)"(\w)` by `(\w)'(\w)` but for instance it doesn't replace s"t by s't but by (\w)'(\w).

● I also can't limit the _Replace_to the bookmarked lines because there are other `"` on the lines that I don't want to change into `'`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide some example text for both before and after your required changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must refer to the words before and after the " as capture group. (See more on Google or here for example; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286068/regex-find-replace-in-notepad). I am not super familiar with notepad++ syntax, but have solved the same problem in Visual Studio. The concepts of capture groups are the same.

Try using the replace syntax

```
\1'\2
```

And it should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: It's working! I would have like to know how to search in marked text but I guess, I will have to wait for a later version of notepad++...